# bootstrap affix cover the div when use ScrollSpy because of position fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap affix cover the div when use ScrollSpy because of position fix. Is there any option to get a certain space above the div to avoid cover the menu bar ?

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOyZGq

[image]

```css
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#details-dropdown li a').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    window.location = this.hash;
    $("#details-menu li").removeClass("active");
    $('#details-menu li a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mynav" style="padding-top:70px;">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My details <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="details-dropdown">
              <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#myabout" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">About</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#myprofile" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Profile</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#mymessage" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="home">
        <div class="jumbotron form-group">
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non magnam eius voluptatum dignissimos aspernatur quas ab, consequuntur aliquid earum veniam. Fuga maiores possimus distinctio unde quae, corrupti perspiciatis adipisci, inventore!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non magnam eius voluptatum dignissimos aspernatur quas ab, consequuntur aliquid earum veniam. Fuga maiores possimus distinctio unde quae, corrupti perspiciatis adipisci, inventore!</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" id="details">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Details</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added within <code>#wrap</code> with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>.container</code>.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam consequuntur vel repellat, quis eveniet, obcaecati, quod voluptatibus vero nobis non suscipit praesentium doloremque atque laudantium sint quidem. Perspiciatis ut, qui!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam consequuntur vel repellat, quis eveniet, obcaecati, quod voluptatibus vero nobis non suscipit praesentium doloremque atque laudantium sint quidem. Perspiciatis ut, qui!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam consequuntur vel repellat, quis eveniet, obcaecati, quod voluptatibus vero nobis non suscipit praesentium doloremque atque laudantium sint quidem. Perspiciatis ut, qui!</p>
        <p>Back to <a href="../sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>My details</h1>
        <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs" id="details-menu">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#myabout" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">About</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#myprofile" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#mymessage" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="myabout">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="myprofile">
            <h2>Profile</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="mymessage">
            <h2>Message</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur cupiditate natus quos incidunt pariatur saepe laudantium minima ipsam vero, illum vitae sint nisi consequuntur tempore repudiandae magnam placeat, quidem dolorum?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```